# can't check type in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I need to check the type of the following function,

```
 summer p q r x = (p.q)(r x)
```

But the compiler says:
 parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'

Comment: In short: use a newer ghci, add `let` to the beginning of your definition, or put your definition in a file and load it.